# PHP "Ternary Like" Boolean Expression Curiosity

Tags: php, boolean, operation

This is just more of a "why does it work" and "why or why not use it" type question.

We all know PHP expressions using ternary operations

```
$var = (isset($i) ? true:false);
```

But in PHP something like the following works too. (It is not ternary, 3 parts, it is more of a binary operation, 2parts.)

```
$var = true;
isset($i) || $var = false;
```

Which may not be so practical :)  but a more useful construction is

```
isset($i) || exit();
```

So the above (much better looking imo) would have the same result as

```
if(!isset($i)) exit();
```

But other than the common

```
defined('CONSTANT') || define('CONSTANT','FOO');
```

I rarely see this type of construct used in PHP. Why does this work? What is it called. Why is it not taught or used more. Are there cons to using it? And is there practical ways to use `&&` in the same way?

Comment: FYI, `$var = (isset($i) ? true:false);` is just a convoluted synonym for `$var = isset($i);`

Comment: it is called "logical or". and it is lazy - meaning: if the first part is true, there is *no need* to evaluate the second part, because the result always *will be* true. similar to and: the second part will only be evaluated if the first part is true. for more information: see **[the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)**

Comment: @ Alvaro Right. it was a just an example of the ternary construction.

Comment: @skribe But, for some reason, many developers actually think that there are never enough parenthesis and booleans are never boolean enough ;-)

Comment: @Álvaro That is unfortunately very true (correct (right (accurate (unerring (flawless))))).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález preemptive parentheses prevent pesky priority problems ;) (although, in the given example, it *is* superfluous)

Answer (score 1):

This way of writing statements also exists in C, Perl and other languages, it plays with how the compiler evaluates statements chained with logical operators.

Imagine you have an expression `if (a() or b())`, then when `a()` returns true you don't have to evaluate `b()`, because the entire statement is true already. So `b()` is only called when `a()` is false. You can write this without the `if`, it still works the same way.

This shorthand is usually found like you described, to define default values or exit if a condition is not met.